# Angular Selected Value NOT showing if open the table more than once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I open the table at the first time (or on hard reload), the table loads fine and the selected values are showed. Below is the html:

```
<select id="userSelect" class="auto_width ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="selected_user" ng-options="user for user in user_stats.user_full_names" ng-disabled="disable">
    <option ng-class="testIdTarget" value="" class="done_searching"></option>
    <option value="0" label="abc">abc</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected" label="def">def</option>
</select>
```

However, when I close and open the table on the second time (without a hard reload), my SELECTED value doesn't show up. YET, my html page is exactly the SAME WITH the selected value.

I spent a fair amount of time ( ~ 4 hours) digging into this issue. But it doesn't make sense to me because the DOM is exactly the same when do the diff between different rendering. Could you point me to the right direction where I should looking?

Comment: Can you provide us a working fiddle of the snippet?

Comment: `when I close and open the table on the second time` How are you doing this close and open..